# Why is tnsping not reliable from ports 20, 21, 22?

Tags: oracle, tnsnames, tns

I think it's not reliable because those ports are used for FTP, SSH and SFTP but I am not sure that's the correct response in respect for Oracle DBA

Comment: I think you're confusing `tnsping` with `ping`. `tnsping` is protocol (TNS) specific

Answer (score 1):

Read this carefully: [Using the TNSPING Utility to Test Connectivity from the Client](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/netag/testing-connections.html#GUID-BE15FEF5-5FCA-4291-90CB-EE75C0A496E0)

Take a look at the Stack Overflow answer: [When using tnsping, can I specify a port number along with the SID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193228/when-using-tnsping-can-i-specify-a-port-number-along-with-the-sid)

You can specify destination port in `tnsnames.ora` or I think you can use [EZCONNECT syntax](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT).